# Understanding results of netlib fftpack

Tags: python, c++, ios, signal-processing, fft

I need to implement a cross platform STFT in C++ that can be called both from python and can be compiled to run on iOS/Android. I have chosen to use [fftpack](https://www.netlib.org/fftpack/) since it is lightweight and seems to do the FFT quite fast.

I have written test code in C:

```
int n = 8;
float wsave[2*n + 15];
int ifac[n+15];

float arr[8] = {11.0, 3.0, 4.05, 9.0, 10.3, 8.0, 4.934, 5.11};


// initialize  rfftf and rfftb
__ogg_fdrffti(n, wsave, ifac);

// forward transform of a real periodic sequence
__ogg_fdrfftf(n, arr, wsave, ifac);


// Print result
std::cout << "[";
for(int k=0; k<n-1; k++){
    std::cout<<arr[k] << ", ";
}
std::cout << arr[n-1] << "]" << std::endl;

// Result: [55.394, -5.58618, 1.66889, 12.316, 3.11, 6.98618, -0.0991108, 5.174]
```

To try my code I ran the scipy `rfft` on the same array:

```py
arr = np.array([11.0, 3.0, 4.05, 9.0, 10.3, 8.0, 4.934, 5.11])
res = np.real(rfft(arr, n=8))
print(res) # Prints [55.394      -5.58617928 12.316       6.98617928  5.174     ]
```

Why does scipy have fewer values. It looks like scipy is consequently skipping some values from the same result array, but why? How to read the correct FFT values from `arr` in C++?

Comment: When I wrote my answer below I didn't even try the `numpy.real(...)` function you're using (it _is_ `numpy.real()`, right?), but now I have. It returns exactly the same array as you get from the C++ version too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the same values from your C++ program as you do in your python script. It's just that you throw away the imaginary parts in the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from scipy.fftpack import rfft

arr = [11.0, 3.0, 4.05, 9.0, 10.3, 8.0, 4.934, 5.11]
res = rfft(arr, n=8)
print(res)
```

Output

```
[55.394      -5.58617928  1.66888853 12.316       3.11        6.98617928
 -0.09911147  5.174     ]
```